# (New Object()).Method() in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, constructor

Apparently, this does not work.

WHY ???????

I don't want to do all this just to call my function:

```
Dim x as new Object()
x.Method()
```

Why do I have to do this in two lines when I can in one.

Comment: Are you new to VB.Net? If so, don't let something new kick your butt. :O)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add the Call keyword.

```
    Call New Page().DataBind()
```

This causes the object to be created before passing to the Call statement.

Yes, I agree, `(New Object()).Method()` seems more intuitive.

Comment: Great, I would have never thought of that.

Comment: BTW I was thinking would it not have been nice if we could just call the New method like a regular one? Like this Object.New(). Too bad this is not the case.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you don't want to make the method static?

```
public class foo
    public shared sub sayFoo
        console.writeline("foo")
    end sub
end class
```

then call sayFoo like.

```
foo.sayFoo
```